# Error in composer install laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, composer-php

Im trying to integrate Stripe using php. I installed laravel and composer.I included composer.json im ny project directory.
I'm trying to execute the first code in php:

```html
<?php
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_dlYHzAc5IOD9cU7ceCEHQ7Jm");
\Stripe\Charge::retrieve(
  "ch_18XDiTGhJYImFJKGejlLqJiy",
  array('api_key' => "sk_test_dlYHzAc5IOD9cU7ceCEHQ7Jm")
)
?>
```

But in my localhost I take this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOZfE.png)

This is the content of my composer.json file(a part of it where i included stripe API libraries):

```html
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
     "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
  },
```

Then I run *composer install* in cmd and this is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqPOV.png)
Can someone help me to get rid of this error?I've been stuck for days with that.
Regards,

Comment: Could you provide the content of the composer.json?

Comment: @Tacsiazuma I inserted in the question.

Comment: The stripe/stripe-php folder exists in the vendor folder? Or the "stripe/stripe-php" key exists in the composer.lock file?

Comment: @Tacsiazuma Yes The stripe/stripe-php folder exists in the vendor folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the vendor/autoload.php in order to gain access to composer autoloader features:

```
 include_once('../vendor/autoload.php'); // assuming you are including it from the public folder.
```

Comment: Use it exactly as I provided. The "../" matters.

Comment: Then this is the error:Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'No such charge:

Comment: Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: The uncaught exception means that you could utilize the composer autoloader, so your problem is solved. The exception you provided is another problem.

Comment: Thanks! It helped!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP library installed via Composer. Simply add stripe/stripe-php to in composer.json file:https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#php-library

Comment: I ve added it.The composer.json file content is in my question.

Comment: Use namespace.Try :  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('my_key');